# JSON unmarshal in nested struct

Tags: json, go, struct

I am trying to unmarshal an incoming JSON into a struct that contains an array of structs. However I get the error

> "Invalid input. JSON badly formatted. json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field DataInput.Asset of type app.AssetStorage"

I have tried to recreate the code here: https://play.golang.org/p/RuBaBjPmWxO, however I can't reproduce the error (although the incoming message and code are identical).

```
type AssetStorage struct {
    Event         string   `json:"Event"`
    EmployeeID    int      `json:"EmployeeID"`
    EmployeeEmail string   `json:"EmployeeEmail"`
    PerformedBy   string   `json:"PerformedBy"`
    Timestamp     string   `json:"Timestamp"`
    AlgorithmID   string   `json:"AlgorithmID"`
    AlgorithmHash string   `json:"AlgorithmHash"`
    Objects       []Object `json:"Objects"`
}

type Object struct {
    ShortName   string `json:"ShortName"`
    Hash        string `json:"Hash"`
    DestroyDate string `json:"DestroyDate"`
}

type DataInput struct {
    Username string
    Token    string       `json:"Token"`
    Asset    AssetStorage `json:"Asset"`
}

func main() {
    var data DataInput
    json.Unmarshal(input, data)
    data.Username = data.Asset.EmployeeEmail
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", data)
}
```

Comment: Where is `input` defined? As it should be a byte array of data.

Comment: `asset` is a JSON array, so the `Asset` field must be a slice of `AssetStorage`.

Comment: If you're having trouble unmarshalling JSON, please include a sample of the JSON data in the body of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three bugs in your code, one is that your are not using address of `DataInput` struct when you are unmarshalling your JSON.

This should be:

```
var data DataInput
json.Unmarshal(input, data)
```

like below:

```
var data DataInput
if err := json.Unmarshal(input, &data); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
```

One Piece of advice in above code. Never skip errors to know more about the error

Next as the error says:

> Invalid input. JSON badly formatted. json: cannot unmarshal array into
>   Go struct field DataInput.Asset of type app.AssetStorage

`DataInput.Asset` should be an array of json objects there you should change your `AssetStorage` to `[]AssetStorage` in your declaration in `DataInput` struct.

One more error is that you are declaring the type of `EmployeeID` field for `AssetStorage` struct to be an `int` which should be a `string`

Working Code on [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/taGvAHvDWYK)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error message:

> Invalid input. JSON badly formatted. json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field DataInput.Asset of type app.AssetStorage

The json you're parsing has `DataInput.Asset` as an *array* of `AssetStorage` objects. So, the type needs to be `[]AssetStorage`.